# RegularExpression Validation on a DataBound GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

Is it possible to validate an already bounded gridview?

```
A | B | C | D
2 | 3 | a | 5
```

For example, I wanted to check if the data inside the columns are non-letters.
In this case, I wanted to highlight or something to tell that there's a letter in Column 2 Row 2.

Comment: on second thought, i think i can just change the cell's css style during RowDataBound. Or is there an easier way? Also, I don't think I know the what to put inside the IF statements if I'm going to do it in RowDataBound. There are other columns that I wanted to check the string length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick.

```
Regex numeric = new Regex(@"^\d+$");

void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    // check out all cells in the current row
    foreach(var cell in e.Row.Cells) {
        // do some validation thingy
        if(!numeric.Match(cell.Text).Success) {
             cell.CssClass = "error"; // put error class on the cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i skip headerrow in rowdatabound?

Comment: got it, if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)